# javascript wont read all contents in elements of an array in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am working on a web app that asks the user for an estimated cost for some items and am using a javaScrpit function to create the fields required. `

```
    var fields = ['Base Estimate or SI', 'Betterment (deducted) <$30k or 10%', 'Deductions (if incl in Base Est)', 'Variations', 'Demolition', 'TC Foundation Costs', 'Scoping Report Costs', 'Geotech Report Costs', 'Engineering Costs', 'CWI Premium Costs', 'Architectural / Design Costs', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other','LA Fees Costs','Legal Fees','Loss of Rent'];
    function add_reserve_figure_fields() {

        for(i = 0;i< fields.length;i++){
            var objTo = document.getElementById("reserveFigureFields");
            var divtest = document.createElement("div");
            divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="reserveFigureFields"><div class="col-lg-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reserveFiguresDescripton" value='+ fields[i] +' readonly/></div><div class="col-lg-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="reserveFiguresNote" placeholder="Enter source of data"  /></div><div class="col-lg-3"><input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" name="reserveFiguresAmount" placeholder="Amount" /></div><div class="col-lg-12"></div></div>';
            objTo.appendChild(divtest)
        }

    }
</script>
```

The fields initialize correctly and work as I expected but for each field that's created  only the 1st word of the string in the element gets printed. 
for example in the first field I would expect Base Estimate or SI to be displayed but only Base is displayed.

I have searched for hours but can't find a similar problem or any explanation. I would assume I have something wrong or have not called for the element correctly to retrieve the string.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRytt.png)

Comment: Try something like `value="'+ fields[i] +'" readonly/>`  Note the extra quotation marks.

Comment: That worked! but why? my thought process through that was that the Strings were being stored as whole strings so when they were called upon they would be displayed as a whole string. I guess I don't understand why it would split the string at the first space. (JS is new to me)

Comment: In HTML attribute values with spaces must be quoted. You were generating `<div value=Base Estimate or SI>`, which is equivalent to `<div value="Base" Estimate or SI>`.

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
value='+ fields[i] +'
```

and it should be:

```
value="'+ fields[i] +'"
```

you do not wrap your string value in quotes.